# How to capture a word when it's not followed by hyphens, underscores, and alphanumeric

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

How do I capture a word "entity", when it's not followed by hyphens, underscores, and alphanumeric, and ignores anything else that follows it?

For example, I want to capture the word "entity" in the following situations:

- `entity`
- `entity,`
- `[entity]`

But I do NOT want it to capture the word in the following situations:

- `entity-foo`
- `entity_bar`
- `entityfoobar`
- `entity0foo`

The furthest I got to is:

```
(entity)[^-\$a-zA-Z_0-9]
```

However, the above regex identifies:

- `entity,` without ignoring the `,`
- `entity]` without ignoring `]`

I'm trying to capture this token in a [Sublime Syntax](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html#match_patterns) definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [lookaheads](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)!

Something like this should work:

```
(entity)(?=[\s,\]])
```

## Explanation:

- <strike>`(?<=\[)?`: The `(?<=regex)` construct is a lookbehind. We make it optional by using a trailing `?`. This lookbehind looks for a `[` character in front of our regex</strike>
- `(entity)`: Matching the phrase `entity` and capturing it
- `(?=[\s,\]])`: A lookahead (`(?=regex)`), looking for any of `\s`, `,` and `]`. `\s` in RegEx matches a whitespace character, which includes spaces, tabs, newlines, etc.

One caveat of my pattern is that the phrase `entity]` will be matched, without the leading `[`, which isn't specified in your examples. This can potentially be [expanded further](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html), but it will begin to get messy, and may not be necessary, anyway.

Comment: Actually, `(entity)(?=[\s,\]])` was enough! It worked like a charm! Thank you! (might want to edit your answer though)

Comment: Indeed, the optional lookbehind is entirely useless! My intention was to make it optional, but that was a lot harder than probably necessary for this solution, and I didn't edit my answer late! Fixed.

Comment: Thank you, David!

Answer (score 0):

For the examples posted by the OP and by the rules, "when it's not followed by hyphens, underscores, and alphanumeric", one could also use *negative lookaheads*:

```
entity(?![0-9a-zA-Z_-])
```

which says in essence match `entity` as long as it is *not* followed by a digit, alphanumeric, `_` (underscore) or `-` (hyphen).

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KxxQtP/1/)